# WHMCS - Disable Module Buttons in Product Page

Tags: module, provisioning, whmcs

Ive written a provisioning module for WHMCS and attached it to a product but the module presents 6 buttons, Create, Suspend, Terminate, Change Package, and Change Password. I dont need these buttons as they make no sense for my module, instead I have some custom ones that do what I need, how do I remove these buttons from the product page?

Can't find anything on the WHMCS documentation to describe how to remove or even change the text of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Custom Functions](https://developers.whmcs.com/provisioning-modules/custom-functions/) in the [Provisioning Modules documentation](https://developers.whmcs.com/provisioning-modules/)?

To add client area buttons/functions:

```
function mymodule_ClientAreaCustomButtonArray() {
    //Add or remove items as required
    $buttonarray = array(
     "Reboot Server" => "reboot",
     "Custom Label" => "customlabel",
    );
    return $buttonarray;
}

//customlabel implementation
function mymodule_customlabel($params) {

    # Code to perform customlabel action goes here...

    if ($successful) {
        $result = "success";
    } else {
        $result = "Error Message Goes Here...";
    }
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: Sorry it has nothing to do with the client area buttons. I have now discovered that if a provisioning module has a button handler function present it renders the Button automatically, so when I used the sample provisioning module code provided by WHMCS it had the shell coe for all the functions supported, little did I know and it does not seam to be documented that this also causes the product page buttons to render.